# Create a list of index names of a pandas dataframe if condition is met

Tags: python-3.x, list, dataframe, filter, conditional-statements

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like:

```
    A   B   C
e  34  89  90
f  92  90  40
g  45  67  80
h  76  25  98
```

I want to iterate over each row of a column and check if value > 80
if the condition is met, I want extract the index name and append to a list.
What's the best way to do so?

The resulting list should look like:
`['f','e','f','e','g','h]`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `stack` after transposing your dataset:

```
df1 = df.T.stack()
df1[df 1>= 80].reset_index().level_1.values
['f' 'e' 'f' 'e' 'g' 'h']
```